# Read and write data to cookie in arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, cookies

What I'm trying to achieve is to store 2 arrays in a cookie, like: ``` ["reminder1","reminder2"]``["time1","time2"] ```

The two ` characters are meant to separate the two arrays.

With the current code that I have, the cookie just gets a value of `reminder1,time1`, and that's it.

I'm literally doing something wrong here, but at this point, I have no idea how to fix this.

My code so far:

Markup:

```
<table id="reminders">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Emlékeztető szövege</td>
            <td>Időpont</td>
            <td>Műveletek</td>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="remdef">
            <td class="remtxt"><em>Kattints a módosításhoz!</em></td>
            <td class="remtim"><input type="text" class="datepicker"></td>
            <td class="remope" style="opacity:1.0;"></td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
var addnew_html = '<span class="typicn plus '+readCookie('nev')+'" onclick="remtbl(\'addnew\')"></span>';
var modify_html = '<span class="typicn edit '+readCookie('nev')+'" onclick="remtbl(\'modify\')"></span>';
var remove_html = '<span class="typicn times '+readCookie('nev')+'"  onclick="remtbl(\'remove\')"></span>';

$('#reminders tbody tr.remdef td.remtxt em').click(function(){
    defhtml = '<em>'+$(this).html()+'</em>';
    $(this.parentNode).html('<textarea width="100%" cols="50" id="rem-editing" class="rem-edit'+$('#reminders tbody tr').index($(this).parents('#reminders tbody tr'))+'"></textarea>');
    changeModifOptions($('#reminders tbody tr.remdef td.remope'),['addnew']);
});

function changeModifOptions(selector,options){
    $(selector).html(function(){
        return  ((!(options.indexOf('addnew'))) ? addnew_html : '' )+((!(options.indexOf('modify'))) ? modify_html : '')+((!(options.indexOf('remove'))) ? remove_html : '');
    });
}

function remtbl(cmd){
    if (cmd == 'addnew'){
        var cookieval = readCookie('reminder');
        createCookie('reminder',($('#reminders tbody tr.remdef td.remtxt textarea').val().replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;')+','+$('#reminders tbody tr.remdef td.remtim input.datepicker').val()+( (cookieval) ? '``'+cookieval : '')),parent.longtime);
        $('#reminders tbody').append('<tr class="remelm"><td class="remtxt">'+Array(readCookie('reminder').split('``'))[0]+'</td><td class="remtim"><input type="text" class="datepicker" value="'+Array(readCookie('reminder').split('``'))[1]+'"></td><td class="remope" style="opacity:1.0;"></td><tr>')
        changeModifOptions($('#reminders tbody tr td.remope:last'),['modify','remove']);
        $('#reminders tbody tr.remdef td.remtim input.datepicker').val('');
        $('#reminders tbody tr.remdef td.remope').html('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your string.split in javascript takes a regular expression, the backtic might mean something there and have to be escaped.  Try using a different delimiter like comma to see if it works.

Comment: @EricLeschinski That's not the case.

Comment: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) ?

Comment: @Andreas The parse was what I needed I think, but how do I implement it?

Comment: "Pseudo" code as your code isn't that readable for me (at least in my current situation^^) `var cookieval = [ ["reminder1","reminder2"], ["time1","time2"] ]; saveCookie(JSON.stringify(cookieval)); cookieval = JSON.parse(readCookie());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andreas suggested you can turn the array into JSON string using `JSON.stringify( array)` and return it to a javascript array using `JSON.parse( string)`

Example

```
var arr=['a','b','c'];
var json=JSON.stringify(arr);

createCookie('reminder', json);

var arrayFromCookie= JSON.parse( readCookie('reminder'));
```

For older browsers that don't support JSON object include json.js library

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of javascript string.split takes either a character or a regular expression.  In the code you posted, you have done neither of these.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

To make it a valid regular expression, use slash backtic backtic slash.  Like this:

```
/``/
```

Comment: But still, adding a regular expression doesn't change the fact that the cookie is not being set properly.